# I am trying to get my HTML navbar fixed to the top but some part of the banner is getting hidden if I do that.. What do I do?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am trying to get my HTML navigation menu fixed so that it stays fixed to the top even when you scroll, but some part of the banner is getting hidden if I do that.. When I apply a margin-top property, it suddenly gets applied to the navigation menu instead. what do I do?

Also, how do I get the text to be completely in the center?

Here is the code:

```css
body, ul, li
        {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .wrapper
        {
            width: 96%;
            max-width: 1200px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 0 2%;
        }
        header
        {
            background-color: #000;
            padding: 10px 0;
            height: 50px;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .logo
        {
            margin: 0;
            margin-top: -13px;
            background-image: url("logo.svg");
            background-size: 85px 85px;
            float: left;
            width: 85px;
            height: 85px;
        }
        header nav
        {
            float: right;
        }
        header:after
        {
            content: "";
            clear: both;
            display: block;
        }
        header nav li
        {
            list-style-type: none;
            float: left;
            margin-left: 20px;
            margin-top: 20px;
        }
        header nav li a
        {
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 15px;
            color: #FFF;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }
        header nav li a:hover
        {
            color: #007bff;
        }
        .main-banner
        {
            width: 100%;
            height: 400px;
            background-image: url("banner-img.png");
        }
        #main-banner-text
        {
            text-align: center;
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 52px;
        }
        .main-banner img
        {
            width: 100%;
        }
        h1#main-banner-text 
        {
            margin-top: 0px;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }
        .main-banner:after
        {
            content: "";
            clear: both;
            display: block;
        }
        .main-content
        {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
        }
        .left
        {
            left: 0;
            width: 75%;
            text-align: left;
            line-height: 1.5;
        }
        .right
        {
            width: 25%;
            text-align: right;
            align-content: right;
            margin-left: 20px;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
        .left h4
        {
            font-size: 20px;    
            color: #007bff;
            font-family: helvetica;
        }
        .left p
        {
            font-size: 20px;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
        .left ol
        {
            margin-top: 10px;
            font-size: 25px;
        }
        #end
        {
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
        iframe
        {
            width: 100%;
            height: 500px;
        }
        .right img
        {
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
        footer
        {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            background-color: #39729b;
            padding: 30px 0;
            font-size: 12px;
            letter-spacing: .05em;
            color: #afcbe0;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }
        .footer-logo
        {
            margin: 0;
            background-image: url("logo.svg");
            background-size: 50px 50px;
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
        }
        footer p
        {
            margin-left: 10px;
        }
        footer a
        {
            margin-right: 5px;
            margin-left: 5px;
            margin-top: 0;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Angel Investors VS Venture Capitalists – Which One Is Right For You? – Dan Martell</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="logo"></div>
            <nav>
                <div class="menu"></div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Meet Dan</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">The A.C.E growth engine<sup>TM</sup>Masterclass</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">saas academy</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
                </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div class="main-banner">
        <h1 id="main-banner-text">Angel Investors VS Venture Capitalists - Which One Is Right For You?</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="main-content">
        <div class="left">
            <h4>
                How are angel investors different from venture capitalists?
            </h4>
            <p>
                Both invest in businesses. Both can write you big checks. Both have the power to help your business growth with a cash injection you otherwise would never get.
            </p>
            <p>
                Are they the same?
            </p>
            <p>
                Heck no.
            </p>
            <p>
                I found this out the hard way...
            </p>
            <p>
                When I was raising money for my 4th company Flowtown, I really didn't know enough about investors.
            </p>
            <p>
                I got some pretty weird looks when they read my terms sheets.
            </p>
            <p>
                I didn't understand their expectations. And all I had to go on were stories from colleagues, and a head full of wrong assumptions about what investors are looking for.
            </p>
            <p>
                I started on the wrong foot. But eventually, I learned how to do it right...
            </p>
            <p>
                So when it was time to raise funds for my next business, Clarity.fm, I knew what the investors were looking for.
            </p>
            <p>
                And I nailed it.
            </p>
            <p>
                I closed $1.6M in funding..
            </p>
            <p>
                <em>
                ...in 3 days!
            </em>
            </p>
            <p>
                It pays to know who you’re talking to and what they want. Trust me.
            </p>
            <p>
                So I want to clear the air so you know the difference and you don’t raise money from the wrong people with the wrong expectations.
            </p>
            <p>
                That’s what this week’s video is all about.
            </p>
            <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/gUQD2i1RuUQ" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            <p>
                In this video, you’ll discover the difference between angel investors and venture capitalists down to 5 specific criteria:
            </p>
            <ol>
                <li>Source of money</li>
                <li>Investement thesis</li>
                <li>Pitching style</li>
                <li>Check size</li>
                <li>Investment filter</li>
            </ol>
            <p>
                By the way, I’m also an investor myself, having invested in 40+ companies. 
            </p>
            <p>
                But I am an angel investor, and not a venture capitalist.
            </p>
            <p id="end">
                Hit play on the video and let’s go over the differences.
            </p>

        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <img src="side-img1.png">
            <img src="side-img2.png">
            <img src="side-img3.png">
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <footer> 
        <div class="footer-logo"></div>
        <p>&copy 2020 Dan Martell. All Rights Reserved </p>
        <a href="#">Terms of Service</a>
        <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `position:fixed` to header. Add `margin-top:70px;` to main banner as the total height of header is 10px(Padding-top) + 50px(height) + 10px(padding-bottom).

Check code snippet.

```css
body,
ul,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 96%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 2%;
}

header {
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

.logo {
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: -13px;
  background-image: url("logo.svg");
  background-size: 85px 85px;
  float: left;
  width: 85px;
  height: 85px;
}

header nav {
  float: right;
}

header:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}

header nav li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

header nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

header nav li a:hover {
  color: #007bff;
}

.main-banner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  margin-top: 70px;
  background-image: url("banner-img.png");
}

#main-banner-text {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 52px;
}

.main-banner img {
  width: 100%;
}

h1#main-banner-text {
  margin-top: 0px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.main-banner:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}

.main-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.left {
  left: 0;
  width: 75%;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.right {
  width: 25%;
  text-align: right;
  align-content: right;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.left h4 {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #007bff;
  font-family: helvetica;
}

.left p {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.left ol {
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

#end {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

.right img {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: #39729b;
  padding: 30px 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: .05em;
  color: #afcbe0;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.footer-logo {
  margin: 0;
  background-image: url("logo.svg");
  background-size: 50px 50px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

footer p {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

footer a {
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Angel Investors VS Venture Capitalists – Which One Is Right For You? – Dan Martell</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="logo"></div>
      <nav>
        <div class="menu"></div>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Meet Dan</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">The A.C.E growth engine<sup>TM</sup>Masterclass</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">saas academy</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </nav>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div class="main-banner">
    <h1 id="main-banner-text">Angel Investors VS Venture Capitalists - Which One Is Right For You?</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="main-content">
      <div class="left">
        <h4>
          How are angel investors different from venture capitalists?
        </h4>
        <p>
          Both invest in businesses. Both can write you big checks. Both have the power to help your business growth with a cash injection you otherwise would never get.
        </p>
        <p>
          Are they the same?
        </p>
        <p>
          Heck no.
        </p>
        <p>
          I found this out the hard way...
        </p>
        <p>
          When I was raising money for my 4th company Flowtown, I really didn't know enough about investors.
        </p>
        <p>
          I got some pretty weird looks when they read my terms sheets.
        </p>
        <p>
          I didn't understand their expectations. And all I had to go on were stories from colleagues, and a head full of wrong assumptions about what investors are looking for.
        </p>
        <p>
          I started on the wrong foot. But eventually, I learned how to do it right...
        </p>
        <p>
          So when it was time to raise funds for my next business, Clarity.fm, I knew what the investors were looking for.
        </p>
        <p>
          And I nailed it.
        </p>
        <p>
          I closed $1.6M in funding..
        </p>
        <p>
          <em>
                ...in 3 days!
            </em>
        </p>
        <p>
          It pays to know who you’re talking to and what they want. Trust me.
        </p>
        <p>
          So I want to clear the air so you know the difference and you don’t raise money from the wrong people with the wrong expectations.
        </p>
        <p>
          That’s what this week’s video is all about.
        </p>
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/gUQD2i1RuUQ" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        <p>
          In this video, you’ll discover the difference between angel investors and venture capitalists down to 5 specific criteria:
        </p>
        <ol>
          <li>Source of money</li>
          <li>Investement thesis</li>
          <li>Pitching style</li>
          <li>Check size</li>
          <li>Investment filter</li>
        </ol>
        <p>
          By the way, I’m also an investor myself, having invested in 40+ companies.
        </p>
        <p>
          But I am an angel investor, and not a venture capitalist.
        </p>
        <p id="end">
          Hit play on the video and let’s go over the differences.
        </p>

      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <img src="side-img1.png">
        <img src="side-img2.png">
        <img src="side-img3.png">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <footer>
    <div class="footer-logo"></div>
    <p>&copy 2020 Dan Martell. All Rights Reserved </p>
    <a href="#">Terms of Service</a>
    <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```